# Uses for MachineKey in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, viewstate, machinekey

What different ways are Machine Keys useful in asp.net?
I think the following are correct but thought there may be more.

1. Multiple applications can use the same cookie
2. Multiple servers can work with the same viewstate

Comment: @Ben found this question while looking for another info, added some missing info in an answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MachineKey is used for:

- ViewState encryption and validation
- Forms Authentication (or Federated Authentication) uses this key for signing the authentication ticket

Having a Web App installed on multiple servers requires same Machine Key configured on all of them in order for Load Balancing to work.

To see all details, please refer to: [MSDN How To: Configure MachineKey in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx#paght000007_machinekeyexplained)

Answer (score 18):

Machine key is also used to encrypt/decrypt the webresources.axd parameters.

Even on a single server the machine key should be configured, because any recycle of the app domain will generate a new key when it is set to auto. This causes the next postback just for pages rendered before the recycle, to cause a viewstate validation error, and also issues with the resources during that time.

Answer (score -3):

Encryption - very common.

Comment: The values in the cookies and viewstate are encrypted based on the MachineKey.  Could you say what else is being encrypted?

Comment: f.e. passwords by membership provider could be encrypted using machine key

Comment: @mikus: Which is a bad idea. Hashing with a unique salt per user should be used instead.

Comment: pretty old stuff :D I don't think i meant encryption of user passwords to be stored in db, rather credentials to be used by the system, dont remember now