# MVC 4 simplemembership login from app on phone

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, windows-phone-8, simplemembership

I have a site running mvc4 with simplemembership provider.

I want to let my users access the same data on a phone (ios, android, wp8) as on a webpage, hence I need them to logon to the same user database as my MVC.

How do I verify the password from the app against the database? the phone app not from a webbrowser on the phone... a native phone app :)

Don't know if the question is clear, if it's not, let me know :)

To be more specific:

I need to login from my app, with the same username and password as I would do on the website... I'm using the simplemembership provider which is part of the webmatrix.webdata.websecurity on the webpage and it's obviously not available for the phone sdk... any hints?

Comment: The same way you verify the password from the MVC site against the Database. Unless I misread your question.

Comment: It is not clear as to why you think it would be handled any differently on a smart phone in a web browser as opposed to a web browser on a PC.

Comment: well... I didn't say it was from a webbrowser on the phone, I wrote "from the app", meaning an app != webbrowser :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use your bdd like an web app for retrieving your password. It's the same way for an website. Or i need more explanation

Comment: I need to login from my app, with the same username and password as I would do on the website... I'm using the simplemembership provider which is part of the webmatrix.webdata.websecurity on the webpage and it's obviously not available for the phone sdk... any hints?

Comment: For wp8, you can use your stuff with web security for the others mobile i think that you can create a web service who use your simplemembershipProvider.. it's simpliest ..
or you can write a custom membership provider and keep a compatibility with the others mobile because the problem is how to encrypt/decrypt your cookies... If you want do that you can setting your machinekey in web.config (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550210/uses-for-machinekey-in-asp-net)) 
is it usefull ?

Comment: what do you mean by "you can use your stuff"?